# Guava - Google Cache - loadSuccessCount is always 0

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm using guava cache and it prints below. loadSuccessCount and totalLoadTime is always zero.

> CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=13, loadSuccessCount=0,
>   loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=6}

Initially all were 0 and I started recording the stats. Still loadSuccessCount is zero. It is supposed to return the number of times Cache lookup methods have successfully loaded a new value.

Please help why is this is not giving right value.

Code:

```
com.google.common.cache.Cache<Object, Object> newCache = CacheBuilder.from(configurations).recordStats().build();

public void put(String key, Object o) {     
    newCache.put(key,o);    
}

public Object get(String key) {     
    Object o = newCache.getIfPresent(key);      
    return o ;
}
```

Update:

In stats, loadSuccessCount, loadExceptionCount, totalLoadTime - These are applicable for LoadingCache. Not applicable for simple Cache which I'm using.

Comment: Look at the other values `hitCount=0, missCount=13`. Something isn't right here.

Comment: We can't say what some code is supposed to do, why it behaves in a certain way, without seeing any line of code. Post the code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @JB Nizet I have added the cache builder and get, put methods code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am able to see good hitCount after some time. "CacheStats{hitCount=25, missCount=17, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=9}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted code never lets the loader load anything:

- the first method puts a given object into the cache, under a given key. The loader is thus not involved
- the second method gets the value associated with the given key if it's already present, and doesn't do anything it not present. So the loader is not involved either.

In fact, you don't even have a loading cache, so the number of loads will always be 0.

Comment: Can you please explain a little about loader? sorry for not having better understanding abut this cache.

Comment: A LoadingCache is a cache which is built with a Loader function. Typical example: you want to cache web pages. So you create a cache with a loader. The loader's job is to get the web page based on its key: the URL of the web page. When getting the page for a given URL from the cache, the cache looks if it already has the web page. If it does, it returns it. Otherwise, it calls the loader, then stores the returned web page and returns it. See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained for more details.